# Dynamic input fields using codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

i'm having a hard time implementing a dynamic input fields just like this [sample](http://www.codexworld.com/add-remove-input-fields-dynamically-using-jquery/) to my codeigniter. I tried doing it but didn't worked. I was hoping anybody could help me with this one.

This is my code:

```
<?php $inputs = array(//        [0]title        [1]name             [2]type
        array('Account Title'   ,'account_title'    ,'text')
        ,array('Description'    ,'description'      ,'text')
        ,array('Debit'          ,'debit'            ,'number')
        ,array('Credit'         ,'credit'           ,'number')
    );?>

    <div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
        <?php foreach ($inputs as $i){?>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3 no-padding">
                <span class="input-group-addon input-head"><?php echo $i[0];?></span>
            </div>
        <?php }?>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
    <?php foreach ($inputs as $i){?>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3 no-padding">
            <?php switch($i[1]){
                    case 'account_title':?>
                        <select name="<?php echo $i[1]?>">
                    <?php foreach($account_titles as $ac){?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $ac['id']?>"><?php echo $ac['account_title']?></option>
                    <?php }?>                                           
                        </select>
                    <?php break;
                    default:?>
                        <input  value="<?php echo set_value($i[1]); ?>"
                                class="form-control"
                                placeholder="<?php echo $i[0]; ?>"
                                name="<?php echo $i[1]; ?>"
                                type="<?php echo $i[2];?>"
                                <?php echo ($i[2]=='number')?'step="any" min="0"':''?>>
                    <?php break;
                }?>
                <?php echo form_error($i[1]) ? '<div class="text-danger">' . form_error($i[1]) . '</div>' : ''; ?>
            </div>
    <?php }?>
    </div>
```

Currently it look like this:

[image]

I want it to look like this, that when add button is click, the row input fields and drop down would duplicate, and it would delete when the button delete is click. Just like in the link above.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where is `$account_titles` array?

Comment: The sample you refer to is heavily depending on jQuery, but you show no jQuery code? Also "didn't work" is a brief error explanation. Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the different approach for your solution.

I have created the Fiddle for you may be it can help you.

See it live here:
<kbd>[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ankit29/pzwoj491/6/)</kbd>

here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
<button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="mytext[]" placeholder="Account Title">
    <input type="text" name="mytext2[]" placeholder="Description">
    <input type="text" name="mytext3[]" placeholder="Credit">
    <input type="text" name="mytext4[]" placeholder="Debit">
</div>
</div>
```

The Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]" placeholder="Account Title"><input type="text" name="mytext2[]" placeholder="Description"><input type="text" name="mytext3[]" placeholder="Credit"><input type="text" name="mytext4[]" placeholder="Debit"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});

</script>
```

You just have to change the name of the input field. I hope it helps.