# How to generate questionnaire form with a MySQL table?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a "questionnaire" table which contains `question_id`, `question`, and `variable_scored` (with rows like `variable1`, `variable2`, etc.) fields.

What I'm trying to do is generating an HTML questionnaire form based on the content of the table like so

"Question 1 here"
4 radio buttons inputs value for variable1

"Question 2 here"
4 radio buttons inputs value for variable2

Here's my code of current still static form

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="input2" class="col-sm-12">Question Here</label>
  <div class="col-sm-12">

    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="variable1" value='4'>4</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="variable1" value="3">3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="variable1" value="2">2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="variable1" value="1">1</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is *very* specific. Can you please make it more general?

Answer (score 0):

I thing you can fetch all details from controller and pass this array into view file.

And view file you can just assign this value like.

```
<label for="input2" class="col-sm-12"><?php echo $data['question'] ?></label>

<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $data['variable1'] ?>" value='4'>4</label>
</div>
```

You can try this one may it works for you.

I provide you also link for you.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538804/dynamic-input-fields-using-codeigniter)